# Serializing an ICollection to JSON

Tags: c#, javascript, json, icollection

I am trying to serialize an ICollection to JSON and pass it to my JS via hidden field on my HTML.

So far I have tried:

1. `@Html.HiddenFor(model => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model.Details), 
   new { Id = "WorkOrderDetails" }) 
   // also tried model.Details.ToArray(). model.Details.ToList()`
2. `var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => jsonSerialiser.Serialize(model.Details), 
   new { Id = "WorkOrderDetails" })
   // also tried model.Details.ToArray(). model.Details.ToList()`

It complains about an Incompatibility error: InvalidOparationException

I am thinking at this pace I will need to iterate my ICollection and pass every single detail individually.

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

`HiddenFor` is just a convenience method that helps in simple cases where you're going to pass it a simple expression like `m => m.Details`. Since this is more complicated, it's probably simpler to write your own HTML tag.

```
<input type="hidden" name="Details" 
    value="@jsonSerialiser.Serialize(model.Details)">
```